# Artifacts on Viewport (Waveform/Vectorscope)

Tags: 3d-view, artifacts

Any ideas on why am I getting all kinds of artifacts on the viewport, when selecting waveform or vectorscope?

If I resize the viewport window artifacts change their look and nature, looking more or less weird, but always weird enough to make it almost unusable.

Only a few images where added to the sequencer here, but it happens with videos too. My system is Arch Linux, Blender v3.51.

Thanks!

[image]
[image]

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: This looks like a hardware issue, either you have a faulty graphics card, or this is a driver problem

Comment: Blender's viewport is the only showing an issue, hardly a hardware problem. Drivers might be, it's a Macbook Pro 2015 (Radeon R9 M370X) running on ArchLinux. But still strange that I haven't seen any problems elsewhere.